# Mnesia create table error

Tags: erlang, mnesia

Using following method I have tried to create a table,

```
mnesia_init() -> 
mnesia:create_schema([node()]),
case mnesia:start() of
    ok ->
        try
            mnesia:table_info(type, bill_cdr_file_counter)
        catch 
            exit:_ ->
                mnesia:create_table(bill_cdr_file_counter,[{attributes,[key,value]},
                                                           {disc_copies,[node()]}])
        end;
    {error, Reason} ->
        error_logger:error_report(["Mnesia start error: ", Reason]),
        {error, Reason}
end.
```

the record I have used is the following,

```
-record(bill_cdr_file_counter, {key,value}).
```

but as response I'm getting this,

```
{aborted,{bad_type,bill_cdr_file_counter,{disc_copies,log@mbsmsc1}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine for me.  The first time I run it I get the return value:

```
{atomic,ok}
```

The second time I run it, I get the return value:

```
{aborted,{already_exists,bill_cdr_file_counter}}
```

And when I do:

```
4> observer:start()
```

then click on the `Table View` tab, then in the menu bar select `View>Mnesia Tables`, I see the `bill_cdr_file_counter` table listed. I'm using `Erlang 19.2`.  What version of Erlang are you using?

I also tried:

```
3> node().
nonode@nohost
```

Or, if I start erl like this:

```
$ erl -sname gandalf

1> node().
gandalf@MyMBP
```

You're error message says that `node()` is returning:

```
log@mbsmsc1
```

That's the only difference I see between your code and the code I ran.

Comment: Yes, I got the above error when I include {disc_copies,[node()]} option only, otherwise I receive {ok,atomic}.but the node 'log@mbsmsc1' up and running so I can't understand what is error.

Comment: @Hasitha, Can you ping that node?  Maybe if you describe your setup, someone can figure out what's going on.  How are the nodes started?